# How to get unique values out of a GROUP BY clause

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that has a unique identifier column, a relational key column, and a varchar column.

```
|  Id  |  ForeignId  |  Fruits  | 
--------------------------------- 
|  1   |      1      |  Apple   |  
|  2   |      2      |  Apple   |  
|  3   |      3      |  Apple   |  
|  4   |      4      |  Banana  |
```

What I would like to do, is group the data by the Fruits column, and also return a list of all the ForeignId keys that are in that particular group. Like so:

```
|  Fruit  |  ForeignKeys  |
---------------------------
|  Apple  |  1, 2, 3      |
|  Banana |  4            |
```

So far I have the SQL that I gets me the grouped Fruit values as that is trivial. But I cannot seem to find a good solution for retrieving the ForeignKeyId values that are contained within the group.

```sql
SELECT Fruits FROM FruitTable
```

I found the GROUP_CONCAT function in MySql which appears to do what I need but it doesn't seem to be available in SQL Server 2017.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Jus curious. What will be consuming this data? Just making sure there is a valid reason to denormalize the data that is delivered. If there isn't a reason, then the proper solution might be to adjust what is consuming this result to work with normalized data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are using SQL Server 2014 or older**:

```
SELECT  Fruit       = Fruits 
    ,ForeignKeys    = STUFF(
                            (SELECT ',' + CAST(ForeignId AS VARCHAR(100))
                            FROM    FruitTable t2
                            WHERE   t1.Fruits = t2.Fruits 
                            FOR XML PATH ('')
                    )
                        ,1,
                1,
                ''
                ) 
FROM    FruitTable t1
GROUP   BY Fruits;
```

**If you are using SQL Server 2016 or later, you can also write this simpler way:**

```
SELECT  Fruit = Fruits, ForeignKeys = STRING_AGG(ForeignId, ',')
FROM    FruitTable
GROUP   BY Fruits;
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I miss typed the id as i took it from an old query which i wrote. Thank you for the input. :-)

Comment: Great answer, short and concise. Follow up question. I am using SSMS 2017 and the `STRING_AGG` function shows up with intellisense but I get an error that it is not a recognized built in function. Is this because the actual database is probably a version older than 2016?

Comment: @jwlford , Yes, that should be the reason. Execute this to figure out the version of your SQL Server: SELECT @@VERSION.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fruits,  foreignkeys = STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + foreignid
              FROM fruittable t1
              WHERE t1.id = t2.id
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '') 
from fruittable 
group by fruits
```

This should work.

Comment: there are a couple of things wrong here which will cause this query to fail: 1> you have not provided reference for t2, 2> Assuming you means t2 to refer the outer table, your join should not be on Id column, it should rather be on Fruits column, 3> You can not use the Id column of the outer table inside the FOR XML without selecting that column or using it under GROUP BY.